# Changing eDirectory Password From Linux Machine

Tags: linux, authentication, novell, passwd, edirectory

I have Configured LDAP Authentication for my Linux Machines. The LDAP Server is Novell eDirectory. The LDAP Users are able to login into the machine. But when i am issuing passwd command it is asking LDAP password then asking to give me new password. After that i am getting a message saying that all the authentication tokens are successfully updated.

But when i try to login with the new password into the machine it is not allowing but when i tried with the old password it is allowing me to loign. Even the eDirectory password also didn't got changed?

What's wrong i am doing?

Thanks and regards,

Sunny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to the eDirectory server you are pointing at?  If so, go to iMonitor (https://serverIP:8030/nds/trace) and login, and then in Trace settings (box in the bar with tick marks, and lightning bolts) and clear all, and then enable LDAP tracing.

Refresh and go to Trace Live, then do the password change and look at the trace event from the LDAP server perspective.  Likely something will be revealed there.

Comment: i have tried it from windows machine by installaing novell client initially it got failed. Then i came to know that i have configured password policy for the user. after configuring the password policy it started working. I have not tried it on the linux machine i have to try it out. If i face any problems will let stacky know please help me at that time. I have read your so many articles in cool solutions. they are very very nice.

Comment: So it is an NDS password vs Universal Password change issue, likely.